# Multiple nft markers make the webpage very slow

Tags: ar.js

I have a use case where I need to have 6 NFT markers on a single html page. These markers correspond to a brochure and the images on the brochure would trigger videos. I'm using Ar.js-org version in this project.

My challenge is, when I use 2 markers, everything works fine. The load time is acceptable, videos run fine. But when I add 5-6 nft markers, the web page either loads very slowly, and eventually it crashes. Even when it loads completely, the videos don't run properly. All 6 markers are in the same a-scene tag.

Can someone help me with suggestions on how can this performance issue be resolved?

UPDATE - I tried loading the videoa in separate threads. But it did not work. Even though the videos are loaded in separate threads, the a-nft markers are still loaded on the main thread. So when they load, they look for their a-audio and a-video components. And since they are being loaded separately, the markers load with errors.